# How to get history of mapping for following table data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a history mapping table for UserId changes, where every time when UserId changes, a row for new UserId with old UserId inserted in the history table.
Below is the sample table and data:

```
UserIdNew | UserIdOld
---------------------
    5     |     1    
    10    |     5    
    15    |     10
```

The above data explains that UserId 1 has gone with following transition from UserId 1 -> 5-> 10 -> 15.

I want to query all the Old Ids for a give `UserIdNew`, how can I do it in a single query?

For this case if `UserIdNew = 15`, then it should return `1,5,10`

Comment: You need a recursion solution. These type of solutions are highly database dependant, so tag which DBMS you are using. Also, can ID's be repeated?

Comment: @EzLo, No Ids will not repeat.

Answer (score -1):

If UserIdNew are always greater then previous (older) in a UserIds chain, i.e. if cases like `10->20->5->1` never happen, this query can do the job (not fully tested, `new` and `old` used instead of your field names):

```
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN new=7 THEN @seq:=concat(new,',',old)
    WHEN substring_index(@seq,',',-1)=new THEN concat(@seq,',',old)
    ELSE @seq
  END AS SEQUENCE 
FROM (SELECT * FROM UserIdsTable ORDER BY new DESC) AS SortedIds 
ORDER BY SEQUENCE DESC 
LIMIT 1
```